# Ajax POST can't seem to authenticate with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

Devise refuses to authenticate me when sending an ajax POST request.
What have I missed?

---

- rails (4.1.6)
- devise (3.4.1)
- jquery-rails (2.3.0)
- jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3)

---

**Controller**

```
class SeenEpisodesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user! #Devise

  def mark_episode
    #do stuff
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

end
```

---

**Javascript**
Trying both with setting a header and a payload.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  data: {
    authenticity_token: encodeURIComponent($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
  }
});
```

**I have also tried without setting the tokens myself. `jquery_ujs` sets the header for me!**

Yes I have `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in my layout.

---

**Javascript manifest**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs #Have tried with or without
```

---

**Rails console output**

```
Processing by SeenEpisodesController#mark_episode as JS
  Parameters: {"mark"=>"1", "episode_id"=>"887795", "season_id"=>"65577"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 9ms


Started GET "/account/sign_in.js" for 192.168.0.10 at 2015-02-28 19:44:18 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as JS
```

---

**Dev tools network output**

[image: POST]

[image: Response]

---

[image: POST parameters]

Answer (score 0):

`%253D` - try to decode this part of your `authenticity_token`. It will equal to `=`. So, seems like you have encoded `authenticity_token` incorrectly (twice).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do `encodeURIComponent` when posting with jQuery. jQuery encodes the data for you anyway, which is leading to your data being encoded twice which will result in invalid authenticity token being submitted.

Comment: Reading SO and blogs, the X-CSRF-TOKEN in the header should be enough. I've tried removing the payload with no success. Also, `jquery_ujs` sets the header for me.